# Selenium Webdriver - referencing a non-static - jexcel string as a static

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I had written a data driven script, fed by an Excel doc read in using the Jexcel API and now want to separate my variables into a separate class, but am receiving the "Cannot make static reference to non-static field" error.

Can you advise as to how I may do this, a sample of the 'variable' class is displayed below;

```
//jexcel sheet/cell reference
Cell btcell0 = sheet.getCell(6, 2);
//variable name required to be static
String tNbuyName = btcell0.getContents();
```

Example I've seen which would allow me to reference the variable from another class which produces the "Cannot make static reference to non-static field" error;

```
public static final String tNbuyName = ..............
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign not static value to a static class field. Either the method from which you are getting the value should be a static method or the field tNbuyName  should be non static.

Either make tNbuyName as non static or make a static utility method to get the value and assign it to tNbuyName .

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanks for coming back to me, my understanding for this is getting clearer but I'm still a little cloudy ....

This is the method I'm using from the 'ExcelUtils' class

```
public static void setExcelFile(String Path, int Sheetname) throws Exception {


    try { 
        Workbook workb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(Path));
        Sheet = workb.getSheet(Sheetname);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw (e);
    }
}   


public static String getCellData(int ColNum, int RowNum) throws Exception{

    try {
        Cell = Sheet.getCell(ColNum, RowNum);
        String CellData = Cell.getContents();
        return CellData;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Following that in the 'ResultsMap' class I'm assigning the values for my variables......

```
public class ResultsMap {

public static void WriteTo() throws Exception {

String tNbuyName = ExcelUtils.getCellData(6, 2);
String tNbuyPass = ExcelUtils.getCellData(6, 3);
String tAccName = ExcelUtils.getCellData(6, 4);
String tCasNo = ExcelUtils.getCellData(6, 5); 
etc, etc......
```

but now in the AdminBUser class I want to access the variables as in ResultsMap but how would I do it?

As an example I had been trying System.out.println(ResultsMap.WriteTo(tNbuyName);

But the message is displayed advising that tNbuyName cannot be resolved to a variable

This is the file structure as is......

[Image of package explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRWe4.png)